# org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException while converting spring boot application to spring MVC war

Tags: spring-mvc, jsf, spring-boot, war

i am trying to convert my existing application from spring boot to spring mvc war.

I have done changes to `pom.xml` like changed packaging to war and added following dependency:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
```

created new `web.xml` and added entries for Faces Servlet.

While trying to deploy war on tomcat getting:

> org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException. which is
>   caused by 
>           Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/faces/event/AjaxBehaviorEvent

Answer (score 0):

You're missing javax.faces dependency clearly

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.glassfish</groupId>
  <artifactId>javax.faces</artifactId>
  <version>2.2.13</version>
</dependency>
```